# How to stop control-d from exiting shell in c

Tags: c

I am writing my own shell and I want to stop the user from exiting the shell with `CTRL+D`. Below is how I am checking for EOF and I am able to catch the `CTRL+D`:

However, my loop goes into infinite and does prints `please use _exit` over and over again.

How could I stop this from doing so?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl-D close the input stream? There will never be anything to read.

Comment: if there is a `while` around your snippet, it is the expected behaviour after closing stdin. `read` reads `0` bytes again and again.

Comment: Okay. it sounds like after I hit control and prompt the message, before i do the `continue`, i need to re open stdin

Comment: To get what you want you'll have to disable Control-D in the terminal. In Unix these are termios. Read man tcgetattr and tcsetattr. I think you'll have to entirely disable ICANON, and then terminal handling gets complicated.

Comment: Although maybe you can just unset the VEOF (virtual end of file) character.

Comment: You may find this worth of reading: [How to restart stdin after Ctrl+D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld) .

Comment: Note that if you don't exit on end-of-file being received by your shell, then it won't be compatible will every other shell out there.

Comment: Also note that your reading of the commands needs some work, unless you have made `STDIN_FILENO` non-blocking.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, it doesn't.

Comment: Please post a complete example with details. it's not even clear if you're reading from a tty, what OS you're trying that on. In the case where you're on unix and piping the input through another command (eg. `cat | ./your_shell`) that's expected to happen, and you should rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void disable_veof(void) {
    struct termios t;
    int r;

    r = tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t);
    if(r)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    t.c_cc[VEOF] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;
    r = tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
    if(r)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void echo_lines(void) {
    char buffer[4096];
    const size_t buffer_len = sizeof buffer;
    ssize_t bytes;
    while( 0 != (bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, buffer_len)) ) {
        bytes = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bytes);
        if(bytes <= 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main() {

    disable_veof();
    echo_lines();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is a terminal in canonical mode, `EOF` in raw io (as opposed to stdio where it is) is *not sticky*.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09

> Special character on input, which is recognized if the ICANON flag is
>   set. When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately
>   passed to the process without waiting for a newline, and the EOF is
>   discarded. Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF
>   occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be
>   returned from the read(), representing an end-of-file indication. **If
>   ICANON is set, the EOF character shall be discarded when processed.**

The next `read()` should return a positive value unless the user keeps pressing `Ctrl+D`.