# cin.clear() leave EOF in stream?

Tags: c++, eof

I have a question about `cin.clear()`, my cpp code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
        char c, d;
        cout << "Enter a char: " << endl;
        cin >> c;                            // here I will enter Ctrl + D (that is EOF under linux)
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Enter another char: " << endl;
        cin >> d;

        return 0;
}
```

I compiled and run this code under 2 systems: 
one system is Debian 7 with older version of software like g++ and library

```
 g++ --version
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

another system is Arch linux with newer version of software:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I run this program , I enter Ctrl + D (EOF) when it ask me to "Enter a char: ". The problem is that When I run it under Debian 7, I can Enter a char when the program asks me to "Enter another char: ", but I will not be able to do the same under newer system, the program just finished.

It seems that `cin.clear()` will clear eof bit and flush EOF in the stream under older system, with newer system `cin.clear()` will clear eof bit, but leave EOF in the stream untouched.

Is this caused by some new cpp standards? And why `cin.clear()` behave differenly under 2 systems?

Comment: There is no such entity named "EOF" that exists in any stream. You're asking about the stream status or state.

Comment: The stream doesn't read `Ctrl + D`. It's interpreted by the terminal. So the behavior of `clear` depends on your terminal. I assume that in newer systems it closes the standard input. If that's the case clearing the eof bit doesn't help. The standard input will still be closed.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I did not get any reasonable answer to this question so far.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue in Ubuntu 20.

I find the solution from [How to restart stdin after Ctrl+D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld)

Terminal doesn't really close stdin stream. The stream just return "nothing" to indicate EOF or other troubles.

To clear EOF, calling clearerr(stdin) in your program may solve the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char c, d;
    cout << "Enter a char: " << endl;
    cin >> c;
    clearerr(stdin);
    cout << "\nEnter another char: " << endl;
    cin >> d;

    cout << "\n\nc = '" << c << "' and d = '" << d << "'\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My g++ version is 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
My OS is ubuntu 20 x64
My terminal is gnome-terminal 3.36.1.1