# How would one generalise `clearerr()` under C++?…

Tags: c++, io, buffer, eof, file-descriptor

##### TL;DR

I am aware that if a program listens for **EOF** (e.g. `^D`) as a sign to stop taking input, e.g. by relying on a conditional like [`while (std::cin) {...}`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool#:%7E:text=idiomatic%20C%2B%2B%20input%20loops%20such%20as), one needs to call [`cin.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) before standard input can be read from again (readers who'd like to know more, see [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool#See_also)).

I recently [learned that **this is insufficient**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732434/cin-clear-leave-eof-in-stream), and that *the underlying **C file descriptors***, including **`stdin`**, [need `clearerr()` to be run to forget EOF states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld).

Since `clearerr()` needs a C-style file descriptor, and C++ operates mainly with `std::basic_streambuf`s and the like (e.g. `cin`), I want to generalise some code (see below) to run `clearerr()` on any `streambuf`'s associated C-style file-descriptor, even if that may not be `stdin`.

**EDITS (1&2):**
<s>I wonder if `stdin` is the only ever file-descriptor that behaves like this (needing `clearerr()` to run) ...?

If it isn't, then the following code should end the question of generalisation (idea pointed out by [zkoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12451243/zkoza) in their answer)</s>
As [zkoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12451243/zkoza) pointed out in [their comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330082/how-would-one-generalise-clearerr-under-c#comment122787250_69429495), `stdin` is the only file-descriptor that would, logically, ever need such treatment (i.e. `clearerr()`). Checking whether a given C++ stream is actually really attached to `*std::cin.rdbuf()` is all that is needed:

```cpp
std::istream theStream /* some stream with some underlying streambuf */

if (theStream.rdbuf() == std::cin.rdbuf())
    clearerr(stdin);
```

---

#### Background

I'm writing a tool in C++ where I need to get multiple lines of user input, ***twice***.

I know there are multiple ways of getting multiline input (e.g. waiting for double-newlines), but I want to use **EOF** as the user's signal that they're done — not unlike when you `gpg -s` or `-e`.

After much consultation ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c/36978839), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251433/checking-for-eof-in-stringgetline/2251612), and [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)), I decided to use... (and I quote the third):

> [the] idiomatic C++ input loops such as [...]
>
> ```cpp
> while(std::getline(stream, string)){...}
> ```

Since these rely on [`std::basic_ios::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to do their job, I **ensured that `cin.rdstate()` was cleared between the first and second user-input instructions** (using `cin.clear()`).

The gist of my code is as follows:

```cpp
std::istream& getlines (std::basic_istream<char> &theStream,
                        std::vector<std::string> &stack) {
    std::ios::iostate current_mask (theStream.exceptions());
    theStream.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
    std::string &_temp (*new std::string);
    while (theStream) {
        if (std::getline(theStream, _temp))
            stack.push_back(_temp);   // I'd really like the input broken...
                                      // ... into a stack of `\n`-terminated...
                                      // ... strings each time
    }

    // If `eofbit` is set, clear it
    // ... since std::basic_istream::operator bool needs `goodbit`
    if (theStream.eof())
        theStream.clear(theStream.rdstate()
                        & (std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit));
                        // Here the logical AND with
                        // ... (failbit OR badbit) unsets eofbit
    
    // std::getline sets failbit if nothing was extracted
    if (theStream.fail() && !stack.size()) {
        throw std::ios::failure("No input recieved!");
    }
    else if (theStream.fail() && stack.size()) {
        theStream.clear(theStream.rdstate() & std::ios::badbit);
        clearerr(stdin); //  the part which I want to generalise
    }
    
    delete &_temp;
    theStream.exceptions(current_mask);
    return theStream;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. From what I understand, `cin.clear()` has pretty much the same effect as `clearerr(stdin)`.

Comment: That's what I thought (and had hoped) too! But [apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732434/cin-clear-leave-eof-in-stream) :/
Thanks for replying tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(true);
    char c = '1', d = '1';
    std::cout << "Enter a char: \n";
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << (int)c << "\n";
    std::cout << std::cin.eof() << "\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    clearerr(stdin);
    std::cout << std::cin.eof() << "\n";

    std::cout << "Enter another char: \n";
    std::cin >> d;
    std::cout << (int)d << "\n";
    std::cout << std::cin.eof() << "\n";
}
```

It works because C++'s `std::cin` is tied, by default, with C's `stdin` (so, the first line is actually not needed). You have to modify your code to check if the stream is `std::cin` and if so, perform   `clearerr(stdin);`

EDIT:

Actually, `sync_with_stdio` ensures only synchronization between the C and C++ interfaces, but internally they work on the same file descriptors and this may be why `clearerr(stdin);` works whether or not the interfaces are tied by    `sync_with_stdio`

EDIT2: Does these answer your problem? [Getting a FILE* from a std::fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109449/getting-a-file-from-a-stdfstream)
[https://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/](https://www.ginac.de/%7Ekreckel/fileno/) ?

Comment: Hi! First, thanks for responding!
As you pointed out yourself, I went ahead and resorted to checking if the `std::istream&` passed to my function _was_ indeed `std::cin` in the first place. I did this by testing for `theStream.rdbuf() == std::cin.rdbuf()`.

Comment: Just realised what a terrible piece my original question is, so I'm going to go and tidy it up. The main objective was really to *find a way of **generalising `clearerr()`***.
Now I doubt one will _ever_ come across a `streambuf` other than the one sync'd with `stdin` that will need `clearerr()`…
Still like generalising tho 

Comment: So to sum up, if `stdin` isn't the only file-descriptor which might need `clearerr()` after encountering an EOF, how do I generalise `clearerr()` for any given `std::streambuf`? (which unfortunately can't be translated to a C-like file-descriptor)

Comment: Why should any other stream be of any concern? For `std::cin` there's a "man-in-the-middle": the terminal that processes user's input. If `cin` is attached to a Linux terminal, it will never receive bytes corresponding to `ctrl+C`, `ctrl+Z`, `ctrl+U`, `ctrl+W`, `ctrl+D`. You can tell that `ctrl+D` was pressed only by examining the eof and fail flags (they're both set by ctrl+D).   Why c++ compilers (at least gcc and clang) don't associate the state of a stream with the state as defined by the underlying C library is a real mystery to me. But they certainly do it on purpose.

Comment: You have a really good point about the being an MITM! You're right, I suppose it *is* true that `stdin` is the only file-descriptor that needs special treatment. Thanks, [zkoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12451243/zkoza)!