# Failing to read from std::cin after pipe() with dup2()

Tags: c++

I was trying to read output from a child process using a `pipe()`. I used `dup2()` to get the pipe's output through `stdin`, and `cin.get(c)` in a loop to get the child's output. The first time I do this, everything works fine. After that, however, every time I try to do this again, `cin.get()` returns `EOF`.

I thought that perhaps `cin.clear()` would help, since `cin.get()` is setting the `failbit` and `eofbit` when it reaches `EOF`... This does remove the flags, but the main problem remains: `cin.get()` does not read anything.

Here is a simplified case that shows the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();

    //FIRST TIME
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[1]);
        std::cout << "PROCESS 1 OUTPUT" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    close(fd[1]);
    int original = dup(0);
    dup2(fd[0], 0);
    close(fd[0]);

    if (std::cin.fail())
        std::cout << "FAIL1" << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::string output1;
    while (std::cin.get(c))
    {
        output1 += c;
    }
    std::cin.clear(); // This helps with "FAIL"s, but doesn't fix the problem :(

    if (std::cin.fail())
        std::cout << "FAIL2" << std::endl;

    dup2(original, 0);
    close(original);

    std::cout << "output: " << output1 << std::endl;
    
    //SECOND TIME
    int fd2[2];
    pipe(fd2);
    int pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        close(fd2[0]);
        dup2(fd2[1], 1);
        close(fd2[1]);
        std::cout << "PROCESS 2 OUTPUT" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    close(fd2[1]);
    int original2 = dup(0);
    dup2(fd2[0], 0);
    close(fd2[0]);

    if (std::cin.fail())
        std::cout << "FAIL3" << std::endl;

    char c2;
    std::string output2;
    while (std::cin.get(c2))
    {
        output2 += c2;
    }

    if (std::cin.fail())
        std::cout << "FAIL4" << std::endl;

    dup2(original2, 0);
    close(original2);

    std::cout << "output2: " << output2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs the following:

```
output: PROCESS 1 OUTPUT

FAIL4
output2:
```

What I expected to get was the two outputs and no "FAIL". Do you have any idea why this happens?

I found an alternative solution using `read()` and reading straight from the pipe's `fd[0]`, however I would love to understand why this is happening when I use `cin`.

Comment: once `stdin` sees `EOF` it stops.  trying to find a duplicate.

Comment: This cannot possibly be necessary, but what you are trying to do seems to work if you add `clearerr(stdin)` as well as doing `std::cin.clear()`.  This may just be my bias against C++ and ignorance of the language, but this seems like a forehead slapping wtf? are the language designers thinking here.  Surely `std::cin.clear()` ought to perform the same functionality as `clearerr(stdin)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As William Pursell mentioned, using both `clear()` and `clearerr()` will solve your problem.

After reading around for a bit, I came to the conclusion that this is due to the fact that [`std::cin`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) and [`stdin`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/stdin/) are two different things, and therefore you need to reset their error flags separately:

- `std::cin` is an **object of class [`istream`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/)**, and its internal
  error state flags are set using [`std::cin.clear()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/).
- `stdin` **is actually a `FILE *`**, and its error flags and the EOF indicator are reset using [`std::clearerr(stdin)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/clearerr).
- `std::cin` is **associated with the standard C input stream** `stdin`
  (according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)), but I guess you still need to reset both separately.

These StackOverflow questions and answers might also help:

- [How would one generalise `clearerr()` under C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330082/how-would-one-generalise-clearerr-under-c)
- [cin.clear() leave EOF in stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732434/cin-clear-leave-eof-in-stream)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to provide this answer in the hopes of encouraging someone who understands the quirks of C++ better than I to downvote and provide a more correct answer.  The behavior you want seems to be available if you do:

```
  std::cin.clear(); 
  std::clearerr(stdin);
```

That `cin.clear()` does not also do `clearerr(stdin)` seems bizarre to me, and this is probably why I continue to steer clear of C++.  Although, to be fair to C++, the thing that ought to be avoided here is manipulation of the underlying file descriptors of the standard file streams.