# std::cin doesn't read anymore after reading EOF and clearing

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, eof, istream

I'm reading lines from `std::cin` with a `while` loop that ends when `EOF` is introduced. After exiting the loop, I call `std::cin.clear()` to put the stream back to normal and read again, but it's not entering the second loop.

I've checked the `eofbit` and it's set to `false`. The `failbit` is set to `false` as well and the `goodbit` is set to `true`. The `gcout` after clearing is `0`. Here's the code I'm running:

```cpp
    while (getline(std::cin, person)) {
        // Do stuff until I enter ^D
    }
    std::cin.clear();

    // Adding std::cin >> person here doesn't work either

    while (getline(std::cin, person)) {
        // It never enters this loop
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What platform? There is more than goes into user input than just the C++-layer `std::cin` - maybe your actual pipe closed too. We can't know without knowing what technologies you're using

Comment: I'm working on ArchLinux with all packages updated to date. I'm compiling with g++ and I don't know if that's the info you're referring to specifically :(

Comment: How do you provide input to this program? Using what technologies? Using what commands? In what software? Tell us _everything_ that you're doing, from start to finish.

Comment: What do you mean by "read again"? Read the same data again? Read more input provided _after_ "entering ^D"? Be specific.

Comment: AFAIK, `^D` marks "end of transmission" and is literally the end of the transmission; no postscripts.

Comment: I'm opening the program with my shell (zsh), running it with `./bin/test`, no args. The input is provided from the shell as text text entered by a human from the keyboard. When I say "read again" I mean read another input. I input the text for the first loop correctly and then I cannot input anything anymore. The program just ignores every `std::cin` sentence after that.

Comment: EOF means end of file: There is no more data to read. The only way to read anything more is to change reading position `seekg` if input supports it. Human console doesn't have such functionality (should user type everything again?). For me this question suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have some simple issue and you trying to solve it in weird way and you ask to fix this weird way.

Comment: I undersand the XY problem here, but I have to say this code was given to me written that way by my professor, so I (wrongly) figured that I was doing something wrong, not that it was a weird way to do this. I'm sorry :(

Comment: *^D* is a signal to the linux terminal that you do not intend to enter more data, and I do not believe you can go around this without making your own terminal emulator. Nevertheless, you may find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51194821

Answer (score 1):

The ***std::cin.clear()***  command clean the error flags in cin, so that further I/O operations will work correctly. The clear method don't reset the cin to initial value. The std::cin is a stream, so you can read something only one time.

My suggestion in this case for your purpose is to store the readed lines in a string or in an array of strings, or in the way you prefer and then reads it from the stored data.