# scanf being ignored after '^d' is hit

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm new to C and currently doing homework that happens to deal with `scanf()`

The second `scanf()`is being ignored after I hit `Ctrl+d` twice to exist the first `scanf()`
and I can't figure out why does that happen. In the debugger, I can see that the program skips the second `scanf()`. Is it because something like, `Ctrl+d` ends the input buffer so the second `scanf()` does not get a chance to read anything from the input. I am not professional at using technical terms so my description might be kinda vague.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NODE *list = NULL;
    while (1) {
        char *word = malloc(101);
        if (scanf("%s", word) == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        push(word, &list);
        //free(word);
    }
    int index[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &index[0]);
    }
    pop(index[0], &list);
    pop(index[1], &list);
    pop(index[2], &list);
    printList(list);
    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean Ctrl-D? That means “close this input stream” so there’s nothing to read after that, ever.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen oops, you're right it was ctrl+d, how do I go around it?

Comment: I suggest `clearerr(stdin)`. Please see [How to restart stdin after Ctrl+D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821/how-to-restart-stdin-after-ctrld/51195895)

Comment: Use the [`clearerr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/clearerr) function.

Comment: Best way would to not close the stream with ^D since it most likely isn’t necessary

Comment: If you use `fgets()` for (all) the input (and remove the trailing newline) you can use a blank line as the signal to stop input.

Comment: You could also ask the user to input a special string to mark the end of the first input. For example an empty string.