# Reusing System.in after Ctrl-D

Tags: java

I have two groups of data I need to take from the user of an unknown size, and I would like it if the user could specify the end of their input with Ctrl-D (Ctrl-Z in Windows I believe).

This works flawlessly for the first group, but the second group reads nothing. In fact, after EOF is sent to the console, I'm unable to read from `System.in` at all for the remainder of the program (`readLine()` will always return null).

*How do I effectively "reopen" `System.in` in order to read more inputs after an EOF input?*

Here is some example code to express what I'm trying to accomplish:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader systemIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        String line;
        System.out.println("Enter first inputs (Ctrl-D to close)");
        while ((line = systemIn.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.printf("Received input %s%n", line);
        }
        System.out.println("First inputs have been received!\n");

        // What do I put here to use System.in again?

        System.out.println("Enter second inputs (Ctrl-D to close)");
        while ((line = systemIn.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.printf("Received input %s%n", line);
        }
        System.out.println("Second inputs have been received!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @saka1029 Unfortunately this is not my issue, because the stream isn't closed. if it was closed, the second while loop would throw `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`, which it does not. `readLine` simply always return null.

Comment: Once EOF is reached, it is not possible to reset the stream's state so that you can continue reading from it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem on macOS and Linux with JDK 8 and 12. It reads the second input just fine after Ctrl-D. Are you sure Java's stdin is a tty?

Comment: @JimGarrison So, it's simply impossible to do so in java? I know in C it's as simple as calling [`clearerr(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194821). That would really be unfortunate if this is just a language limitation.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you so much for this post! Turns out, its my IDE (both intellij and eclipse had this issue). If I ran the program just through a Linux terminal, it behaves as I expect, but whatever my IDEs are doing to wrap the standard input causes them to hold on to that EOF character forever.

Comment: IF you have a console attached to the jvm, you can use the `java.io.Console` class, where `readLine()` signals EOF by returning `null` but allows you to continue reading if more input is available.  This does not work in my Eclipse (`System.console()` returns `null` meaning it doesn't think there's a console available) but it works if I run the class in the command line.

Comment: The IDE undoubtedly uses pipes to talk to the process, while this Ctrl-D behavior is specific to tty devices. I would really suggest additionally also accepting a blank line or single dot on a line by itself to end input so that the program can easily be used in other contexts like automation, inetd, or via such an IDE.